# sscanf alternative

Tags: c++, input

How can I do the following without sscanf or cstdio library? I only have iostream, string, and cstdlib for this assignment.

```
sscanf(input.c_str(),"%lf", x);
```

input is a string and x is a new double. not familiar enough with what might be in iostream that might let me easily convert that to something iostream friendly.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ way:

```
std::string x;
double y;
std::istringstream  iss(input);
iss >> x;
iss >> y;
```